# can I integrate payment gateway to transfer money from one to another user? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I want to implement a feature that one user can send cash transfer request to another user by unlocking their image.

The features of app is:

*UserA can send cash request for their snap.
*UserB accept & send image with lock content.

*UserA received image with lock content. When He tries to see original image. A prompt appears to transfer money UserB. 
As he transfers money to UserB successfully. He will see original image of UserB.

This is the flow of my app.

Please help. Is it possible to transfer money through paypal payment gateway.

Question: Would the apple approve the features of my app payment transfer through third party integration to just unlock the snap?

I'm expecting reply soon.

Thanks in Advance.
A. Hameed

Comment: Will apple approve this feature?

Thank you so much for your valuable response.

Comment: yes apple approve this feature

Comment: Thanks Varun for your support.

Comment: Hi Have you implemented this feature. i.e send money from User to another user in IOS.

Comment: @AbdulHameed have you done this user to user payment? If yes, then please let me know. I want guidance in this matter. Thanks.

Comment: No my friend, I had implemented Paypal later on.